# Right word to describe this kind of search

Tags: meaning, expressions

How do you describe the following kind of 'search' in one word?

A blind man searching for a faucet in a room

OR

A normal man searching for a faucet in a dark room

Is it fumbling, scouring, scouting, scrounging, or something else?

Comment: I've got to go for ***fumbling*** (well, I would, wouldn't I? :) According to Google Books, there are 9 instances of [*groped for the alarm*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22groped+for+the+alarm%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), but "About 1,910 results" for [***fumbled** for the alarm*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fumbled+for+the+alarm%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), and I defy anyone to claim they mean slightly different things.

Comment: I think **Fumbling** is more suited for this context

Answer (score 3):

[To grope](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Grope): (from TFD)

> - (usually foll by: for) to feel or search about uncertainly (for something) with the hands
> - to search for something by reaching or touching usually with your fingers in an awkward way
> - to move forward carefully by putting your hands in front of you so that you can feel anything that blocks you

- he groped for the light switch in the dark room
- she groped for the cell phone in her purse.

or:

[feel around](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/feel+about) (for someone or something) and [feel about](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/feel+about)(for someone or something):

> - to try to find someone or something by feel [rather than sight]. He felt around for the soap in the bathtub. She felt about for the dog at the foot of the bed, but it wasn't there. Gerald felt about for a pencil.

Comment: I would be careful about using **grope**.  If the context is clear (i.e. A man was groping about in the dark for a faucet) then you won't have a problem.  But also carries a negative connotation associated with sexual harassment (i.e. He groped her and was sued for sexual harassment).

Comment: Well, context is important, but I don't think you can easily misunderstand the sentences.

Comment: Consider the paired sentences:  "It was dark.  He was groping."  That will immediately conjure a negative connotation for most readers.

Comment: It was dark, he was groping for the light switch!!!

Comment: And in that case, context is clear, so we don't have to worry.  Which is exactly my point.  But if you don't specify context, you may not say what you want to say.

Comment: @Nick2253 The "kind of search" specified in the OP most certainly has an object, so you would be groping _for_ that object, not just groping.

Comment: "It was dark, he was groping for money." could go either way :)

Comment: @DavidK My point is that you can say things like: "It was dark; he was fumbling about" and be perfectly clear.  Or even: "He was searching in the darkness."  But you can't really say the same thing about "groping".  So, when using groping, you have to be extra careful to include the context.

Comment: @Nick2253 "Groping all about" would imply that you weren't sexually harassing a particular individual, although I suppose it could mean you were surrounded by people on all sides and you were harassing all of them. :-) Anyway, _my_ point was that you're addressing a related question, not the main question.

Comment: @DavidK "Ray Charles is groping all about." could definitely be ambiguous. :)

Comment: I'd tend to be cautious about both *fumble* and *grope*, as they both suggest an uncertain motion involving luck or chance. It's perfectly possible, in a familiar environment, to *navigate by touch* even in complete darkness, without the clumsiness of fumbling; I do this in my house every night, and technically it's what blind people do all the time. Most blind people I've met, in fact, do so with much confidence.

Answer (score 2):

> The word you've narrowed down appears to be [the best fit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fumble)-  **fumble** -          *“He
>   fumbled towards the door”*

- feel about uncertainly or blindly
- handle clumsily (metaphorically)

However, fumbling is an uncoordinated movement that *can involve your entire body*, [not just your hands.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fumble)

Answer (score 1):

What if your movements weren't quite as spastic? What if the blind man had been in that bathroom a thousand times? What if the situation called for caution?

"Within the total darkness of the room, he *calculated* the location of the live socket and installed a bulb."

"Unencumbered by the darkness, the blind man *deftly* negotiated the staircase."

(*blind* man/*deft* - kinda cute... n'est pas?)